# What happens when you run a project on a local Tomcat server in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

In an effort to troubleshoot a problem I am having with a Servlet returning a `405` for no explicable reason, I am trying to understand how the Tomcat server works within Eclipse.

So my question is, can someone explain exactly what happens when you right click on that project in Eclipse, and select <kbd>Run on Server</kbd>?

What happens? Where does the project get loaded, or sent to? How exactly does it keep track of which urls correspond to what? Etc, etc. I'd really appreciate a nice explanation or some links to one

**EDIT**

I'm trying to create a Dynamic Web Project

Comment: Some questions first: What kind of project did you choose? (Java project, Web Application Project, Enterprise application project) How is the tomcat integrated into your eclipse?  In short, one can say: the application gets compiled, packaged and then deployed to the tomcat and then the tomcat is started to run the application.

Comment: Eclipse creates its own tomcat instance, and deploys your project there... Specifically to ${workspace}/Server/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/${Project}